# Jquery to get the url of a link

Tags: jquery

`B0011` is a link on my page

```
<a class="ms-listlink ms-draggable" onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="http://demo/sites/Dev/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=%7BA4CF34F4%2D92E9%2D4456%2DA71D%2D6E430115DC12%7D&amp;ID=11&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100A8CBE041E83BA346BCF4EB1F7DE540E7" onclick="EditLink2(this,92);return false;" target="_self" dragid="10" draggable="true">B0011</a>
```

So when I click this link, I need to get the `href` for this link. I hv tried it with jquery

```
jQuery(".ms-listlink").click(function() {  alert($("a", this).attr("href"));});
```

But this does not work..

Comment: Sorry, but your problem is not SharePoint specific given your description and hence should not be asked here

Answer (score 1):

Try to give:

```
href="http://demo/sites/Dev/_layouts/15/listform.aspx"
```

only the page name rest you can call dynamically.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I can not change the link..